# grep that returns string between " characters

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I have a file that looks like:

```
Data.s "intro.png"
Data.s "extended.png"
Data.s "animationen.png"
Data.s "buttons.png"
```

I need a [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) that only returns the string inside the `"` characters.

I tried:

```
grep '"(.*)"' filename
```

That returns nothing.
When I remove the brackets I get every line that matches
I only need the string inside the `"` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk -F\" '/Data.s/ {print $2}' file
intro.png
extended.png
animationen.png
buttons.png
```

Comment: The file contains lines as well that do not look like the lines above. Like empty lines and comments. How would I exclude those?

Comment: @MarkusDöbele Then you should post that in your post.  Have updated my post to only give output if line contains `Data.s`

Comment: @MarkusDöbele, you should first clarify everything in your post. That will help people to give a best answer.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU grep

```
grep -oP '(?<=").*?(?=")' file
intro.png
extended.png
animationen.png
buttons.png
```

Answer (score 0):

grep does not support capturing groups off the bat.
You will need to use the -P flag typically which turns on the Perl RegExp engine for grep.

Since 1_CR already mentions that option, I'll mention a different tool for job.

`sed`

```
$ sed 's/^.*"\(.*\)"$/\1/' /tmp/so.txt
```

replacing /tmp/so.txt with the appropriate file path.